# Set the order of asp.net validator

Tags: asp.net, validation

I'm using 3 validators to validate the TextBox, but all get triggered when invalid value is entered in the Textbox. But I want to these validators to work in a particular order so that users can resolve these faults one by one.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt_temp" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>                                                  

<asp:CompareValidator ID="cv_txt_temp" runat="server" CssClass="error" ControlToValidate="txt_temp" ValueToCompare="0" Type="Double" Operator="GreaterThanEqual" ValidationGroup="insert" SetFocusOnError="true" ErrorMessage="Must be valid value" Display="Dynamic"></asp:CompareValidator>

<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="rev_txt_temp" CssClass="error" SetFocusOnError="true"
 runat="server" ErrorMessage="Value upto 1 decimal place" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="txt_temp" ValidationExpression="\d+(?:(?:\.|,)\d{0,1})?" ValidationGroup="insert"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>


<asp:RangeValidator ID="rv_txt_temp" Display="Dynamic" runat="server" SetFocusOnError="true" ValidationGroup="insert" ControlToValidate="txt_temp" Type="Double" CssClass="error"></asp:RangeValidator>
```

Comment: Also tell us what validators you are using for the textbox

Comment: hi posted the code please check it get trigger when I enter 1.0.0 in text box

Comment: Consider using the [CustomValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.aspx) control. You'll need to write the validation logic yourself, but you'll have full control over what errors to display and in what order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Custom Validator, Custom Java Script or Mask edit validator

Answer (score 5):

The validators that you add automatically add themselves to **Page.Validators collection** in the order they are created. The **validation runs thorugh in the order they are present in the Page.Validators collection** which means the **first validator definition shown in the aspx file is first in Page.Validators.** If you want to change the order, then the only way is to **get all of your validators into the page in the order you want them to fire**.

**Edit :** In your case the only way is to **use css to overlap the validators**.

Comment: hi srinivas but when I enter value such as 1.0.0 then all get trigger as the same time

Comment: hi @srinivas can u explain it with example

Answer (score 0):

You can try with only RegularExpressionValidator

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="rev_txt_temp" CssClass="error" SetFocusOnError="true"   
 runat="server" ErrorMessage="Error.." Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="txt_temp"    
     ValidationExpression="^[1-9]\d*(\.\d{0,1})?$" ValidationGroup="insert"> 
</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

let me know, if you want in other way..

Answer (score 0):

You can create your custom Validation. It will takes time, but you can control order of validation.
You can also use masked textbox extender.

Answer (score 0):

My solution of "setting validation order" is:
On Page where have validators:
1) I set AutoEventWireup to false in aspx code and use custom validators
2) I create and call functions for validations and sett "IsValid" for related validators:

```
 validCustom1.IsValid = Validation1(textbox1.Text);
 if (Page.IsValid)
     validCustom2.IsValid = Validation2(textbox2.Text);
 if (Page.IsValid)
     validCustom3.IsValid = Validation3(textbox3.Text);
 if (Page.IsValid)
 { 
     //Do somethink
 }
 else
 {
     //Do somethink else
 }
```